# Fast Loading web pages

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

We are planning to develop a new website. Our goal is to load web pages
quickly. What are all the techniques we need to follow.

Can anyone give me good suggestions, forums links or articles.

Our platform is PHP, MySQL, Javascript, and AJAX.

Comment: How fast is 'fast'?  What sort of load do you -really- expect?  How is the app going to be hosted? What are you actually going to be doing?  There's a world difference between writing something that's 'fast enough' and something that can handle Facebook-scale loads.

Answer (score 21):

One of the best guides for speeding up your website's load times:

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

---

Update: Google now has an excellent guide as well

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html

Along with an even better [addon for Firefox](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/).  In my testing so far, Google's Page Speed addon is far and above much better than YSlow.  It gives much more detailed analysis and smarter advice (rather than recommending a CDN for small websites like YSlow)

Answer (score 16):

One useful tool is [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) which is a tool from Yahoo that helps identify web page performance problems. Also, Yahoo's [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) is a good list.

However, see Jeff's blog entry [Yahoo's problems are not your problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000932.html) for some perspective on this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Caching caching caching.

[memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/)

[APC](http://php.net/apc)

Pick one, use it. Not having to fetch everything from the database speeds things up hugely.

Comment: Note that memcached & APC are not mutually exclusive - using APC as an opcode cache doesn't rule out using memcached.

Comment: Yeah, APC should definitely be used as opcode, but it actually also supports caching data, a lot of people don't realize. http://php.net/apc_add http://php.net/apc_fetch

Answer (score 4):

Yahoo: "Put Stylesheets at the Top", "Put Scripts at the Bottom".

This sped my recent site up more than any other optimisations.

Answer (score 3):

- Use CSS sprites to keep your HTTP request count down.
- Make sure all your images are a decent size.
- Make sure you have a really good host with good upstream and downstream.
- Make sure your server can execute your scripts in good time, you can check this using the microtime function.
- Make sure your code is optimized properly.

Answer (score 3):

Write as little code as necessary, but not too little.

Less code, less to compile, less to send, less to receive, less to process, less to display.

Answer (score 3):

1) mod_gzip / mod_deflate!  This is such an easy fix I'm surprised it isn't turned on by default.

2) Play tricks with your URL's so you can tell browsers to cache your JS and CSS files forever.  In other words, construct the URL's to look like:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/js/mad_scriptz-v123.js
```

Then use mod_rewrite and strip out the "-v123":

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # http://www.thinkvitamin.com/features/webapps/serving-javascript-fast
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^/(.*)\-v[0-9.]+\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg|xap)$ /$1.$2  [L]

</IfModule>
```

Now apache will go looking for "/js/mad_scriptz.js"...  Every time you change your static content, just bump up the version number to force browsers to reload the content.  I usually have a template variable that contains a global version number that everything gets tied to.  Not the most efficient, but works for my purposes.  If you can tie the version number to your build system or a hash of the file, that would be extra sweet.

Get mod_expires up so all your static stuff expires years from now:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    # all in seconds...  
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A2592000
    ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml A1800
</IfModule>
```

Update: It has been noted that not all browsers or search engines like gzip'd content.  Don't blindly turn it on like I suggest above.  Make sure you don't feed antique browsers gzip even if they accept it (some of them will get pissy with compressed javascript).  The documentation for [mod_gzip](http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/browser.htm) and [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) both have examples that should work fine (I assume they do, or people would email them with changes :-).

I should also mention that it has been my experience that if you've got a reverse proxy in between your mod_gzip'd Apache servers and the world, you need to watch out.  Squid 2.6 will often fool Apache into not gziping stuff when it should and worse, it will cache the uncompressed versions and feed them to browsers that can handle gzip'd content.  Dunno if 3.0 fixes this and I dont know if it is something wrong in my config (doubt it).  Just watch out :-)

That said.  Turn it on. Seriously :-)

Comment: mod_gzip/mod_deflate is not turned on by default for a very good reason: not all major browsers support it flawlessly.  Use with caution.  If you start getting complaints or (more likely) a drop in traffic without a word from users, turn it off.  If not, be happy that your users use smart browsers.

Comment: If constructing URLs like http://www.yourdomain.com/js/mad_scriptz.js?v123 instead of http://www.yourdomain.com/js/mad_scriptz-v123.js you don't need mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

### **1. Enable Keep-Alive**

HTTP Keep Alive refers to the message that’s sent between the client machine and the web server asking for permission to download a file. Enabling Keep Alive allows the client machine to download multiple files without repeatedly asking permission, which helps to save bandwidth.

To enable Keep Alive, simply copy and paste the code below into your .htaccess file.

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

### **2. Disable hotlinking of images**

When other website’s ‘hot link’ to your images it steals bandwidth, slowing your site down. To prevent other sites from hogging your bandwidth, you can add this snippet of code to your .htaccess file. Remember to change the bit that says your_Domain_name.com!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?your_Domain_name.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ – [NC,F,L]
```

### **3. Compress your website with gzip**

Gzip is a simple method for compressing your website’s files to save bandwidth and speed up page load times. Gzip works by compressing your files into a zip file, which is faster for the user’s browser to load. The user’s browser then unzips the file and shows the content. This method of transmitting content from the server to the browser is far more efficient, and saves a lot of time.

You can enable Gzip by simply adding the following code into your .htaccess file:

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

To check whether Gzip is enabled or working properly on your site, you can use Gziptest.com.

### **4. Enable Expires Headers**

Expires headers tell the browser whether they should request a specific file from the server or whether they should grab it from the browser's cache.

The whole idea behind Expires Headers is not only to reduce the load of downloads from the server (constantly downloading the same file when it's unmodified is wasting precious load time) but rather to reduce the number of HTTP requests for the server.

So in .htaccess file include the following things

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Enable expirations
    ExpiresActive On 
    # Default directive
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    # My favicon
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    # Images
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    # Javascript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

### **5. Replace PHP with static HTML where possible**

PHP is great for making your site efficient and reducing the need to enter the same information multiple times. However, calling information through PHP uses up server resource and should be replaced with static HTML where it doesn’t save any time

### **6. Specify a character set in HTTP headers**

For the same reason as above, it’s useful to specify a character set in your HTTP response headers, so that the browser doesn’t have to spend extra time working out which character set you’re using.

You can do this by simply adding a UTF-8 character set tag in your website’ssection.

### **7. Enable Output Compression**

The compression can be done in two ways.

Apache actually has two compression options:

- **mod_deflate** is easier to set up and is standard.
- **mod_gzip** seems more powerful: you can pre-compress content.

Your two options for file compression are Deflate and GZIP.

- Deflate is an option which comes automatically with the Apache server and which is simple to set up.
- GZIP on the other hand needs to be installed and requires a bit more work to install. However, GZIP does achieve a higher compression rate and therefore might be a better choice if your website uses pages which have a lot of images or large file sizes.

Deflate is quick and works, so I use it; use mod_gzip if that floats your boat. In either case, Apache checks if the browser sent the “Accept-encoding” header and returns the compressed or regular version of the file. However, some older browsers may have trouble (more below) and there are special directives you can add to correct this.

> zlib.output_compression   Whether to transparently compress pages. If
>   this option is set to "On" in php.ini or the Apache configuration,
>   pages are compressed if the browser sends an "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
>   or "deflate" header.
>
> PHP Default: Disabled

**In Php.ini**

```
zlib.output_compression = On
```

If you can’t change your .htaccess file, you can use PHP to return compressed content. Give your HTML file a .php extension and add this code to the top:

**In PHP:**

```
<?php 
    if (substr_count($_SERVER[‘HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING’], ‘gzip’))
    ob_start(“ob_gzhandler”); else ob_start(); 
?>
```

This section will turn on the apache mod_deflate module, which compresses text, css, and javascript before it is sent to the browser. This results in a smaller download size. Enable it in .htaccess file so that it looks like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/rss+xml application/x-font application/x-font-truetype application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-otf application/x-font-opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject font/ttf font/otf font/opentype 

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>
```

**

### 8. Enable cache, OPcache, and eAccelerator (Another PHP Caching tool)

Memcache is particularly useful for reducing your database load while bytecode caching engines like APC or OPcache are great for saving execution time when scripts get compiled.

### 9. Take Advantage of Native PHP Functions

Wherever possible, try to take advantage of PHP’s native functions instead of writing your own functions to achieve the same outcome. Taking a little while to learn how to use PHP’s native functions will not only help you write code faster, but will also make it more efficient.

### 10. Cut Out Unnecessary Calculations

When using the same value of a variable multiple times, calculate and assign the value at the beginning rather than performing calculations for every use.
If you’re looping through an array, for example, count() it beforehand, store the value in a variable, and use that for your test. This way, you avoid needlessly firing the test function with every loop iteration.

### 11. Use the Strongest Str Functions

While str_replace is faster than preg_replace, the strtr function is four times faster than str_replace.

### 12. Stick With Single Quotes

When possible, use single quotes rather than double quotes. Double quotes check for variables, which can drag down performance.

### 13. Try Three Equal Signs

Since “= = =” only checks for a closed range, it is faster than using “= =” for comparisons.

### 14. Use isset( )

when compared to

> count( ), strlen( ) and sizeof( ),

isset( ) is a faster and simpler way to determine if a value is greater than 0.

### 15. Cut Out Unnecessary Classes

If you don’t intend on using classes or methods multiple times, then you don’t really need them. If you must employ classes, be sure to use derived class methods as they are faster than methods in base classes.

### 16. Close Database Connections

Un-setting variables and closing database connections in your code will save precious memory.

### 17. Limit Your Database Hits

Making queries aggregate can reduce the number of hits to your database, which will make things run faster.

Comment: Connection-specific header fields such as Connection and Keep-Alive are prohibited in HTTP/2 and HTTP/3. Chrome and Firefox ignore them in HTTP/2 responses, but Safari conforms to the HTTP/2 specification requirements and does not load any response that contains them.

Answer (score 1):

Use a profiler for PHP to make sure your code is executing at a decent speed. Refactor (where possible) if performance could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Some random points.

Render progressively rather than building it in memory and sending at at the end gives a distinct *impression* of speed.

There are some advanced caching tricks you can do, like a forward cache (this is what Akamai do on a grand scale) and separating static and dynamic content.

With PHP particularly, be careful about copying huge amounts of data around. PHP 4 was notorious for this due to it's "copy by default", but it's still a bit too easy to have huge amounts of data to hand in PHP 5. In other words: don't copy (or create!) strings, arrays and objects unecessarily; work with them in place and pass references instead.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to what has been said:

- obfuscate and compress your css
- obfuscate and compress your javascript
- less files == less http requests == faster site == put all your css in one file, put all your javascript in one file

Comment: Compressed javascript has to be uncompressed some time. In the browsers javascript runtime, this is far from fast. Use http level compression instead.

Comment: Huh? Compressed javascript isn't unreadable by the interpreter.  It just takes out all spaces, tabs etc., and replaces local variables so that instead of "myVariable" you have "a".  HTTP compression on the other hand DOES have to be uncompressed by the browser and is a (very small) tax on resources.

Comment: Depends.  I swear I've seen some "javascript compression" that takes your JS, does "real" compression, Base64 encodes it and stores the mess as a javascript variable.  That or I'm nuts.

Comment: I don't find this tecnique very maintainable.

Comment: @collimarco - it depends on your infrastructure - you might have some deployment tools that do the hard work of obfuscation/compression for you when you deploy to production

Answer (score 1):

Compress all your files, inlcuding css and js files also compress your php files.  Do as little database calls as possible and as stated earlier cache all the returns.

Comment: I agree.  One database call which returns several resultsets is better than several separate database calls.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one tip I always find useful:
If you have a lot of tiny images, put them all in one tiled image. In your CSS declarations, control the viewport of the html element by manipulating the x and y coordinates of the background:

```
.icon {
    background-image:url(static/images/icons.png);
    height:36px;
    width:36px;
}
.food {
    background-position:-52px -8px;
}
.icon_default {
    background-position:-184px -96px;
}
```

The tiling can be done in Python script, or by hand if you have a manageable set.

Gmail does this as well. See: http://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/5/greensky/icons7.png

Comment: This technique is called css sprites. I can add that inline css images is also something worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

A project which helps with a few of the points in Yahoo!'s guidelines (http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) is [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) which employs minification, package bundling and conditional HTTP serving in the same space, used with good design practices can significantly reduce page loads, especially user experience (which differs from actually page loading times).

Answer (score 0):

**Best ways to load webpage faster:**

**[*According to yahoo*]**

1-Stylesheet should appear on top loads web page faster.

2-Avoiding redirects.

3-Reduce unnecessary code.

4-Put CSS and JS in external files.

5-Removing duplicate scripts.

Source:
https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

---

**[*According to google*]**

1-Eliminate render-blocking resources

2-Properly size images

3-Defer offscreen images

4-Efficiently encode images

5-Serve images in modern formats

6-Enable text compression

7-Preconnect to required origins

8-Reduce server response times (TTFB)

9-Avoid multiple page redirects

10-Preload key requests

11-Use video formats for animated content

12-Reduce the impact of third-party code

14-Kill Lazy load third-party resources with facades.

---

**Note:** applying the tips can reduce the time significantly. use the points according to your needs.